# Showing white screen on maps fragment but running perfectly on Emulator

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase

I am using Google Maps in my app when I run it on Android device showing a white screen having Google logo at bottom left. But when I run it on Emulator showing maps perfectly

Here is MapsActivity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout">

    <include layout="@layout/main_app_bar_layout"
        android:id="@+id/main_page_toolbar" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/cast_libraries_material_featurehighlight_inner_radius">

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_below="@id/main_page_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MapsActivity"
        tools:ignore="NotSibling" />



    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header_layout">

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is MapsActivity.java

```
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener {

// toolbar instance
private android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar mToolbar;
RelativeLayout rootLayout;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerlayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;
private NavigationView mNavigationView;


//Request code
private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1998;
private static final int PLAY_SERVICES_REQUEST_CODE = 1999;

//Google APi client
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
private Location mLastLocation;
Marker mCurrentMarker;
private GoogleMap mMap;
double lattitude, longitude;

//Map intervals
private static int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 5000;
private static int FASTEST_INTERVAL = 3000;
private static int DISPLACEMENT = 10;

//Firebase
DatabaseReference mUserDatabase, locationDatabaseRef;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;


@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


    //Custom Toolbar
    mToolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_page_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Control Child");

    mDrawerlayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerlayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);
    mDrawerlayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
    mToggle.syncState();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    // Firebase initialization
    mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
    locationDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Locations");

    mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_home);

    mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {

            if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.navigationAccount) {

                Intent profileIntent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                startActivity(profileIntent);
                mDrawerlayout.closeDrawers();
            }
            if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.navigationSettings) {

                Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
                startActivity(settingsIntent);
                mDrawerlayout.closeDrawers();
            }
            if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.navigationContact) {

            }

            return false;
        }
    });

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    //set contentView
    CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
            .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/Arkhip_font.ttf")
            .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
            .build()
    );

    setUpLocation();

}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

    switch (requestCode) {

        case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                if (checkPlayServices()) {

                    buildGoogleApiClient();
                    createLocationRequest();
                    displayLocation();

                }
            }

            break;

    }
}

private void setUpLocation() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        requestRuntimePermission();
    } else {
        if (checkPlayServices()) {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            createLocationRequest();
            displayLocation();
        }
    }
}

private void displayLocation() {

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        lattitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
        longitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();

        //Updating to firebase

        locationDatabaseRef.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())
                .setValue(new Tracking(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail(),
                        mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid(),
                        String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()),
                        String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude())));


        mMap.clear();
        mCurrentMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(lattitude, longitude))
                .title("You are Here"));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lattitude, longitude), 12.02f));


        /*if(!hasAnimated){
            hasAnimated = true;
        }else {
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lattitude, longitude), 12.02f));
        }*/
    }

}

private void createLocationRequest() {

    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(DISPLACEMENT);
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

}

private boolean checkPlayServices() {

    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {

            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this, PLAY_SERVICES_REQUEST_CODE).show();

        } else {

            Toast.makeText(this, "This device is not supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();

        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}

private void requestRuntimePermission() {

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
    }, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);

}

private void startLocationUpdates() {

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }

    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);

    mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    displayLocation();
    startLocationUpdates();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    mLastLocation = location;
    displayLocation();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.connect_item) {

        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialog.setTitle("Make Connection");
        dialog.setMessage("Please use ID shown in profile");

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        final View connect_layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.connect_layout, null);

        final MaterialEditText connectID = connect_layout.findViewById(R.id.connect_id);

        dialog.setView(connect_layout);

        dialog.setPositiveButton("Connect", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();

                //validation
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(connectID.getText().toString())) {
                    Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "Please enter ID", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                    return;
                }

                mUserDatabase.orderByChild("uniqueID").equalTo(connectID.getText().toString())
                        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {


                                    // giving connected user data Log.d("QueryLog",dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
                                    // Getting lattitude and longitude
                                    //Log.d("userLoc", dataSnapshot.getValue().);
                                    //Log.d("LocationIser", locationDatabaseRef.child(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString()) + "/" +  );
                                    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Yo ! Connected Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                } else {

                                    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "User Not Exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });
            }
        });


        // this is cancel btn for dialog
        dialog.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog.show();

    }

    // Logout is here

    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.logout) {
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
        Intent MainIntent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, StartActivity.class);
        startActivity(MainIntent);
        finish();
    }

    if (mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }

    return true;

}

}
```

Here is Android Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="MY_PACKAGE_NAME">

<!--
     The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
     location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".StartActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ProfileActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".MapsActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".MapsActivity">
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Here I have Attached two Screenshot for both condition

1. When App Runs on Android Device : Device Image

[[Device Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egSnp.jpg)]

2. When App Runs on Emulator : Emulator Image

[[Emulator Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntjpH.png)]

Here is the Logcat error when using Signed Release Apk in Emulator:

```
Google Maps Android API: Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start for how to correctly set up the map.
Google Maps Android API: In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
    API Key: YOUR_KEY_HERE
```

I have Enabled "Google Maps Android API " . And API key exists .
**But , I didin't find "Google Maps Android API v2"**. Is it same as "Google Maps Android API" ?

Comment: Are the Google Play Services installed on the device ?

Comment: Not this must be the answer, but did you declare your Google API key in the Android manifest XML file?

Comment: @ArthurAttout Play Services are installed

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks , I declared **API KEY** in Android Manifest and also tried regenerating new API Key . But error not resolved

Comment: Post your manifest.xml

Comment: Possible duplicate of [google maps white screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48242089/google-maps-white-screen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding SHA-1 fingerprint for **signed** Apk at google maps api dashboard solved my problem .

Answer (score 0):

In your Manifest.xml you have to rename activity like this:

```
android:name="com.project.me.appname.Activitys.MapsActivity"
```

Comment: Thanks for answering here . You are correct at your point , I have done  as you have said and also pasted GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY in Manifest.xml. After that I have added SHA-1 for both debug and released apk in Google Developer Console -> Credentials -> "API restriction " .And ,  Thats solves my problem .